# Using pngfix with jQuery 1.4.4

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I use jQuery 1.4.4 and tried two different pngfix plugins

1. http://blog.pauljamescampbell.co.uk/about-2/png-fix/
2. http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/

starting pngfix

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery("#header img").pngfix();
});
```

gives an error

```
jQuery("#header img").pngfix is not a function
```

any ideas?

Comment: Which one are you trying? The second one has a capital 'F'. Have you definitely included the script correctly and after jQuery?

Comment: What do your `<script>` tags look like?

Answer (score 2):

Since the PNG issue is specific to IE (and only older versions of it at that), I'd avoid using a solution like a jQuery plugin where all browsers would need to run at least some code.

A solution like the original [iepngfix.htc](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/) is more elegant since it uses an IE-specific feature (CSS behaviors), so only IE will even see it, meaning the other browsers don't have to run any unnecessary code.

Having said all that, if you still want to use the jQuery solution (and there are occasions when it may be better), the answer is probably what @Rup said in the comments - check that you've spelt the function name correctly, including capital letters. On examples on the pages you linked, one of them specifies the function call as `.pngfix()` (with a lower case 'f'), but the other one specifies `.pngFix()` (upper case 'f').

ps - you've got my sympathy if you're still having to develop code to support IE6  :(